# React is not passing state to mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to pass an array of items(state) in `mapStateToProps`. However i get an empty array or it shows `undefined`.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {DeletePost, GetPosts} from '../actions/';

const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
   state = {
      posts: [],
      loading: true,
    }

  getPosts = () => {
    Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_POSTS)
    .then( (res) => {
       this.setState({
          posts: res.data,
          loading: false
        })
    })
    // console.log(this.state.posts);
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getPosts();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // doesn't show posts in here
    console.log(this.props.posts)
    this.props.GetPosts(this.state.posts);
  }
  onDelete = (id) => {
    Axios.post(`/api/posts/delete/${id}`);
    this.setState({
      posts: this.state.posts.filter(post => post.id !== id)
    })
  }


  render() {
    const {loading, posts} = this.state;
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList DeletePost={this.onDelete} posts={posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  posts: state.user.posts
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  // newPost: (post) => dispatch(newPost(post)),
  // DeletePost: (id) => dispatch( DeletePost(id))
  GetPosts: (posts) => dispatch( GetPosts(posts))
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

**Reducer.js**

```
import {  GET_POSTS} from '../actions/';

const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[]
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // doesn't get posts
        case GET_POSTS:
            return({
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
```

**actions**

```
export const GetPosts = (posts) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {  
        dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, posts })
        console.log('this works i guess', posts);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is mapDispatchToProps in your code?

Comment: Your `mapStateToProps` is inside the class `Post` ? You first add sample code correctly, then expect help from others..

Comment: let me fix the code, sorry .

Comment: I apologize for that.

Comment: ignore GetPosts it does not do anything.

Comment: In `mapStateToProps` if you print the state, can you see the empty `posts` array in the `user` property? If so then the issue is connecting your component to the store. If `posts` in undefined then the issue would likely lie in Redux somewhere, e.g. issue with the store loading your reducer and its default values

Comment: i get `undefined`

Comment: im about to update this.

Comment: their is no posts that show in the array

Comment: Is there supposed to be parentheses in your reducers return statement?  Shouldn't it just be `return{...state, posts: action.posts}` not  `return({...state, posts: action.posts})`

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: this is wierd, it seems that this.state.posts is not showing anywhere in console.log, but i can see the posts mapped on the front end. I can see post title, post content, post time etc. So I think you gave me the solution but their is something that im missing.

Comment: You are calling `this.props.GetPosts(this.state.posts);` after you are trying to log `this.props.posts` to the console and in the same `componentDIdMount()` function.  Try and log it to the console in your render and see what happens.

Comment: nevermind im all good, im going  to bed, i cant think straight. Thx for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you not to save posts in two places. That somewhat defeats the purpose of using redux. You actually don't need post as a state variable in `Posts` class. Whenever there is a new state in redux store associated Class will fall into updation cycle.

Also, you can have a look at `redux-thunk` if you are making api calls.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

It will help you move api fetching logic to actions and reducers and thus rendering your views clean.

Change this

```
export const GetPosts = (posts) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {  
        dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, posts })
        console.log('this works i guess', posts);

    }
}
```

to

```
export const GetPosts = (posts) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_POSTS)
            .then( (res) => {
                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, res.data })
             })
        })
    }
}
```

Change this

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.getPosts();
  }
```

to

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.GetPosts();
  }
```

Now you wont be needing a `componentDidUpdate`.

Also, if you are wondering how to show Loading... till the api call is not completed, you can add a key isFetching to your store.

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isFecthing: false
}
```

and can add an action something like ChangeFetchStats

```
export const GetPosts = (posts) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: CHANGE_STATE, false});
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_POSTS)
            .then( (res) => {
                 dispatch({type: CHANGE_STATUS, true);
                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, res.data })
             })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it may take time over a network to get a POST response. In such case, if ur component gets mounted, it will make a call to the action, but because it takes time, you will get response empty/ undifined posts array.
To prevent this from happening, you can go with following :

```
    componentDidMount(){
this.props.GetPosts(this.state.posts);

   if(!this.props.posts){
    console.log(this.props.posts);
}

  }
```

A little tweek in the render method may help too:

```
render() {
    const {loading, posts} = this.props;
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
{ posts &&(
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList DeletePost={this.onDelete} posts={posts}/>
      </div>
    );)}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So i finally found a purpose for [componentDidupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

The app took a little bit long to load posts maybe half a second.

So by calling `componentDidUpdate`, i get the posts after its finished rendering.

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.props.GetPosts(this.state.posts);     
  }
```

Along with another solution by @stevek

change this

```
 case GET_POSTS:
        return({
            ...state,
            posts: state.posts
        })
```

to this

```
import {  GET_POSTS} from '../actions/';

const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[]
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // doesn't get posts
        case GET_POSTS:
            return{...state, posts: action.posts}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And i can see it after its rendered

[image]